# How do I recursively append a unique identifier to a series of identical strings in bash?

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop, grep

I have a file called test2.txt with below contents:

```
string_9989 1.000 1.4567
string_9989 1.001001 1.2345
string_9989 1.1111111 2.22222222 3.33333333
string_9989 1.0000 1.4567 2.3456
string_1234 1.000000 1.3456
string_1234 1.3456 2.3456 3.5678
string_1234 1.234 3.456 5.678 6.789
string_1234 1.2 3.4 4.5 5.6
```

The first instance of string_9989 correlates to the first instance of string_1234; the second instance of string_9989 correlates to the second instance of string_1234, etc. I want to extract the line for each instance of the strings and print them to new files (so the line from first instances of string_9989 and string_1234 to 1 file, second instances of each to another file, etc). My thinking was to append an index to each instance of the string and use grep to extract that instance and print to a new file, but I am unable to create the index successfully.

I've tried the below code where I:

- save each unique instance of string_[0-9] to an array
- loop through the array adding _$j to the end of the string using sed

```
#!/bin/bash

mapfile -t string_array < <( grep -Eio "string_[0-9]*" test2.txt | sort -u )

for i in ${string_array[@]}; do
        count_path=$(grep -c $i test2.txt)
        j=0
        while [ $count_path -gt 0 ]; do
                sed -i "$j,/$i/{s/\<$i\>/&_$j/}" test2.txt
                let count_path=$(expr $count_path - 1)
                let j=j+1
        done
done
```

I am expecting this output:

```
string_9989_0 1.000 1.4567
string_9989_1 1.001001 1.2345
string_9989_2 1.1111111 2.22222222 3.33333333
string_9989_3 1.0000 1.4567 2.3456
string_1234_0 1.000000 1.3456
string_1234_1 1.3456 2.3456 3.5678
string_1234_2 1.234 3.456 5.678 6.789
string_1234_3 1.2 3.4 4.5 5.6
```

but instead I'm getting this:

```
string_9989_0 1.000 1.4567
string_9989_1 1.001001 1.2345
string_9989_2 1.1111111 2.22222222 3.33333333
string_9989_3 1.0000 1.4567 2.3456
string_1234_0 1.000000 1.3456
string_1234 1.3456 2.3456 3.5678
string_1234 1.234 3.456 5.678 6.789
string_1234 1.2 3.4 4.5 5.6
```

Why is it not completing the append for the second string? I'm using bash version 4.1.2(1)

Comment: I would recommend that you concentrate on a solution to meet your actual requirement. Otherwise this question is an example of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I see. This is my first post so....I presented my problem and what I've done to try to get there thus far. If you don't have a solution why did you post at all?

Comment: `I want to extract the line for each instance of the strings and print them to new files` - then why are you adding suffixes to the fields? So, you want to extract it or add suffixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to extract the line for each instance of the strings and print them to new files (so the line from first instances of string_9989 and string_1234 to 1 file, second instances of each to another file, etc)

awk to the rescue:

```
awk '{ if (n != $1) { cnt=1; n=$1; }; print $0 > "file" cnt ".txt"; cnt=cnt+1; }'
```

The following script:

```
cat <<EOF |
string_9989 1.000 1.4567
string_9989 1.001001 1.2345
string_9989 1.1111111 2.22222222 3.33333333
string_9989 1.0000 1.4567 2.3456
string_1234 1.000000 1.3456
string_1234 1.3456 2.3456 3.5678
string_1234 1.234 3.456 5.678 6.789
string_1234 1.2 3.4 4.5 5.6
EOF
awk '{ if (n != $1) { cnt=1; n=$1; }; print $0 > "file" cnt ".txt"; cnt=cnt+1; }'

find
tail -n+1 *
```

will generate the following output:

```
./file4.txt
./file1.txt
./file3.txt
./file2.txt
==> file1.txt <==
string_9989 1.000 1.4567
string_1234 1.000000 1.3456

==> file2.txt <==
string_9989 1.001001 1.2345
string_1234 1.3456 2.3456 3.5678

==> file3.txt <==
string_9989 1.1111111 2.22222222 3.33333333
string_1234 1.234 3.456 5.678 6.789

==> file4.txt <==
string_9989 1.0000 1.4567 2.3456
string_1234 1.2 3.4 4.5 5.6
```

- At first we check if the instance differs from the last line
- If it differs, then we reset the `cnt` to one and remember the current instance
- Then we `printf $0` print the whole line into `"file" cnt ".txt"` filename
- After that, we increment the count.
- Input file has to be sorted on the first column.

A bash solution that mimics awk would look like:

```
while IFS=' ' read -r instance rest; do
  if [ "${last_instance:-}" != "$instance" ]; then
    cnt=1
    last_instance=$instance
  fi
  printf "%s %s\n" "$instance" "$rest" >> "file${cnt}.txt"
  cnt=$((cnt + 1))
done
```

Comment: This works and rips through my actual file with a few million records in seconds. Will definitely be getting more familiar with awk. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition to rely on standard unix string processing tools like grep and sed is a good one, and if you take that idea further and add in paste and split, as well as <(process substitution), this task can be very easy:

```
a=`grep string_9989 test2.txt`
b=`grep string_1234 test2.txt`
both=`paste <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b")` # paste them side-by-side
echo "$both" | split -l1 # split into n 1-line files
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU grep, paste and split):

```
paste -d'\n' <(grep 9989 file) <(grep 1234 file) | split -dl2 - file
```

Split `file` in two using two invocation of grep and interleave the files using paste.

Pipe the resulting file into split and the resulting files will be named `file00, file01, file02 etc`.

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your real problem `I want to extract the line for each instance of the strings and print them to new files`:

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{print > "out" ++cnt[$1]}' file
```

With any awk and assuming your real input is sorted like your sample:

```
awk '$1!=prev{prev=$1; close(out); out="out" ++cnt} {print > out}' file
```